# Where is Isolated Storage located on MAC MINI OS X 10.8.1

Tags: .net, macos, silverlight, isolatedstorage

Does anybody know where is Isolated Storage located on MAC MINI OS X 10.8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458794.aspx

Isolated storage is located on `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Silverlight/is` for Mac OS and Silverlight